# What would happen if I do my first push without setting username and email address?

Tags: git, github

Suppose I have created a new repository at Github `https://github.com/<my name>/<repo name>.git`

Here is my current configuration setting:

```
$ git config --list --show-origin
file:.git/config        core.repositoryformatversion=0
file:.git/config        core.filemode=false
file:.git/config        core.bare=false
file:.git/config        core.logallrefupdates=true
file:.git/config        core.ignorecase=true
file:.git/config        remote.origin.url=https://github.com/<my name>/<repo name>.git
file:.git/config        remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Is this the blank state? is there anything wrong with this?

What would happen if I just upload to repository without setting username and email address with `git config`? like this:

Navigate to some folder in my computer, then run:

```
$ git init 
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/<my name>/<repo name>.git
$ git add --all 
$ git commit -m "initial commit" 
$ git push origin master
```

Comment: Note that Git only needs your `user.name` and `user.email` settings during the `git commit` step, not during the `git push` step.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't specify settings for `user.name` and `user.email`, Git will look in several different places for your username and email address, including in environment variables, and finally default to using your system account's GECOS field and form a username from your system account's name and your system's hostname.  This is documented [in the `git-commit(1)` manual page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#_commit_information) in recent versions of Git and in `git-commit-tree(1)` in older versions.

While this provides a default, it is almost certainly not going to produce a valid email address since most people will not have configured their system such that it can receive mail.  Git uses the values at commit creation time, so changing before pushing has no effect.

You can create a test commit to see what it looks like and then run `git log --format=fuller` to see what it produces in the Author and Committer fields.

Comment: In older versions of Git, and also depending on compile-time options, sometimes things go wrong here. There's a bug in several particular versions of Git where `git clone` can actually crash, in one oddball case—I ran into this while working on a Travis-CI setup for a public repository: https://github.com/NetSys/bess/commit/7d96bd1c070489beb68657e4c26f5ffee19c90aa

Answer (score 1):

At the `push` moment? It is irrelevant. The user and mail might be set up at that time. What matters is what was set up when you created the revisions you are going to push. If they hadn't been set up then, git uses default values from the user running the git process when committing.

Comment: Right now I think I don't have a default value for user name and email: when I type `git config user.name` it shows nothing

Answer (score 0):

The default user will be used (global)

Comment: I haven't set the global user name, I think I don't have a default value for user name. When I type `git config user.name` It shows nothing.